# Symfony 1.4 : associate many languages to a table

Tags: localization, symfony1

I have these two tables (simplified) :

```
Website:
  columns:
    user_id:          { type: integer, notnull: true }
    domain_name:      { type: string(30), notnull: true, unique: true }

WebsiteLanguage:
  columns:
    website_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    language:   { type: string(5), notnull: true, country: true }
  indexes:
    website_id_language:
      fields: [website_id, language]
      type: unique
```

Like you see, I would like to associate one or many languages to my websites. I don't want to translate the websites, I only want to associate them to languages like I would do for countries.

I need to display a website form with as many checkboxes as languages. Languages are not in a table, so I don't know how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of languages from `sfCultureInfo`:

```
/*
 * displayLanguage defaults to the current culture set in the session, 
 * or you can supply your own - to override it...
 * this will return an array of all languages like array('en' => 'english')
 */
sfCultureInfo::getInstance($dipslayLanguage)->getLanguages();
```

If youre using an sf form for this you could also just use the handy widget:

```
//in your form

$this->widgetSchema['language'] = new sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceLanguage();
```

However, you probably dont need to associate the languages in the db, except for on records that have translations, and then youd be better off using the I18n features to handle all this for you automatically. Then all you have to do is let the user siwthc the culture and everything will magically appear in the proper language... Granted its a little more complex than that but you can automate most of the grunt work and setup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for ;) When I edit my website form, I would like to have many checkboxes (with values 'fr', 'en', 'sp', etc). If I check 'fr' and 'en', I need symfony to create 2 entries in my WebsiteLanguage table, to associate theses 2 languages to my website.

Comment: I don't need to translate my websites ;) I only need to know which languages are available on my website. I could have the same problem if I wanted to associate many countries to my website (maybe my question would be clearer).